# How to solve this using Angular where it works perfectly in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web-services

Hi I am New to ANgularJs.
I Have a WebService.asmx which expects two parameter and returns a bool variable in MachineAssigned variable now in jQuery It works perfectly but Not in Angulajs
"I have A jQuery Code which works perfectly"

```
$('#saveButton').click(function () {
            var machineNo = $('#machineNumberTextBox').val();
            var empCode = $('#employeeCodeTextBox').val();
            var empName = $('#empNameTextbox').val();
            if (machineNo.length > 0 && empCode.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "WebService.asmx/IsMachineAssigned",
                    method: 'post',
                    data: 'machineNumber=' + machineNo + '&employeeCode=' + empCode,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.MachineAssigned) {
                            $('#divResult').text("Machine " + machineNo + " is already assigned to this " + empCode + " : " + empName);
                            $('#divResult').css('color', 'red');
                        } else {
                            $('#divResult').text("Machine " + machineNo + " is available for this " + empCode + " : " + empName);
                            $('#divResult').css('color', 'green');
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

"But in AngularJS Same logic is not Working"

```
var machineNo = $scope.machine.MachineNumber;
        var empCode = $scope.operator.EmployeeCode;
        //var params = { machineNumber: machineNo, employeeCode: empCode }
        $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: "WebService.asmx/IsMachineAssigned",
            //date: 'machineNumber=' + JSON.parse(machineNo) + '&employeeCode=' + JSON.parse(empCode),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: 'machineNumber=' + machineNo + '&employeeCode=' + empCode,
            datatype: "json"
        }).success(function (resopnse) {
            if (data.MachineAssigned) {
                alert("This Machine already assigned");
            } else {
                alert("This Machine is available");
            }
        })
```

I Tried every Thing Please Help Me

Comment: do you have prior angular experience?

Comment: Can you give more information? What response you are getting, what happens when you step through the code etc...

Comment: i don't have enough ranks to add more then two tags that,s why I can't give more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var machineNo = $scope.machine.MachineNumber;
var empCode = $scope.operator.EmployeeCode;
var params = $.param({ 'machineNumber': machineNo, 'employeeCode': empCode });
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'MultifabsWebService.asmx/IsMachineAssigned',
        data: params,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function (response) { // success function
            console.log(response);
            if (response.data.MachineAssigned) {
                alert("This Machine already assigned");
            } else {
                alert("This Machine is available");
            }
        },
        function (response) { // error function
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Comment: I am having an issue with this code.. response.MachineAssigned is returning undefined why ...???

Comment: I found the solution. I have to use response.data.MachineAssigned. thanks for the help again